# user/terraform is not authorized to perform: ssm:SendCommand on resource:

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, github-actions

I am writing a github action workflow that will connect to EC2 instance using [peterkimzz/aws-ssm-send-command@master](https://github.com/peterkimzz/aws-ssm-send-command) action & run a deployment script. However, it fails with the following error:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::<AccountNumber>:user/terraform is not authorized to perform: ssm:SendCommand on resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:<AccountNumber>:instance/*** because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:SendCommand action
```

I ensure all github secrets have valid values. But I fail to understand why it attempts to execute it as `terraform` user. Nowhere in code, i have used `terraform` user. FWIW, EC2 machine was provisioned using terraform script. But that is a separate workflow.

Workflow code

```
name: 'Staging Deployment Pipeline'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  deploy-backend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    steps:
      - name: AWS SSM Send Command
        uses: peterkimzz/aws-ssm-send-command@master
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_DEV }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV }}
          aws-region: 'us-east-1'
          instance-ids: ${{ secrets.AWS_EC2_INSTANCE_ID_DEV }}
          working-directory: /home/ec2-user
          command: aws s3 cp s3://<BucketName>/deploy.sh /opt/v1/ && bash /opt/v1/deploy.sh
```

Comment: That sure looks like an access issue. Have you fulfilled the [requirements](https://github.com/peterkimzz/aws-ssm-send-command#requirements)?

Comment: Yes, I have added the ssmFullAccess IAM policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a permissions issue. Sounds to me like the other script you used to provision the EC2 instance has created an instance role / user called terraform, that'll be what the instance is using when you run commands on it and it doesn't have the permissions required. I'd take a look in IAM to see if it is there. If you can find it adding the `ssm:SendCommand` policy should solve the issue.

Comment: It was indeed an issue. I added permissions for terraform user. That fixed it.